# Qt QImageReader won't loop, uncontrollable

Tags: qt, loops, gif, qimage

really quick problem here

I'm trying to use QImageReader to read the frames of a Gif, but when the animation finishes, it won't loop. I can't even control which frame is loaded, as using either the ImageReader's read() function to return a QImage OR using QPixmap::fromImageReader() both cause the QImageReader to automatically jump to the next frame. The problem is that they both use the same logic where if it is at the end of the animation, return only null instead of resetting.

Here is the way I'm attempting to work with Gifs: My class has a QTimer and a QImageReader. Upon TimeOut of the timer, I call my "nextFrame()" slot.

```
void GifPlayer::nextFrame()
{
    if (img->currentImageNumber() == img->imageCount()-1)
    {
        img->jumpToImage(0);
    }
    else
        img->jumpToNextImage();
    this->lbl->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImageReader(img));
}
```

I must be making some fundamental problem here - can someone please help me? I've even updated to the latest version of Qt, and it hasn't helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QMovie](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmovie.html) sounds like a better fit for your use case, provided you can use that instead. The following gives the basic idea and will work with a GIF, looping automatically:

```
...

void MyWindow::init() {
  movie = new QMovie("mymovie.gif");
  if(!movie->isValid()) {
    qFatal("Movie not valid");
  }
  movie->stop(); // Ensure stopped.
}

void::MyWindow nextFrameSlot() {
  this->lbl->setPixmap(movie->currentPixmap());
  this->movie->jumpToNextFrame();
}

...
```

Comment: This worked well enough as a work around. I initially refrained from it because I needed to be able to manipulate each frame - however I didn't know there was a jumpToNextFrame() method, so this works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something I've tried, but the `QImageReader` class has the following three methods:

```
int currentImageNumber () const
```

> For image formats that support animation, this function returns the sequence number of the current frame.

---

```
int imageCount () const
```

> For image formats that support animation, this function returns the total number of images in the animation.

---

```
bool    jumpToImage ( int imageNumber )
```

> For image formats that support animation, this function skips to the image whose sequence number is `imageNumber`.

---

It seems to me like it would be possible with the first two methods to determine when you've read the last frame of the animation, and then use `jumpToImage` to jump back to the first frame before the next `read()`.

Comment: Sounds like the GIF `QImageIOHandler` doesn't override the `jumpToImage` method, which would cause the default implementation of that method (which does nothing) to be used. The documentation certainly suggest that it _should_ support `jumpToImage`.

Comment: So how should I progress from here?
If there is no way around this, is there any other way I can load frames of a gif manually?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but not as simple as just using a `QImageReader`. An animated GIF is laid out [like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#Animated_GIF). So for each frame you've got a Graphics Control Extentsion structure, followed by an Image Descriptor, possibly a palette, and then the LZW-encoded pixel data.